# Embedding Facebook Albums in a Website

Tags: php, facebook, api, photo

Is there a way to use the Graph API to retrieve a the photos in a public album from Facebook? Is it possible to do without supplying an access token? If not, is it possible to do without having an access token that expires in 60 days (seems to be the default expiration time).

If I am embedding a Facebook album on a website, I don't want to have to re-authorize or grab a new access token every 60 days and republish my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter if its public or private , you need to add the access token or the it'll not return the data .

Here is the example code

```
$album_id = your album id;
$access_token = 'your token';

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$album_id}/photos?access_token={$access_token}";
$image = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

foreach($image->data as $img){
echo "<img src='{$img->images[6]->source}' />    ";

}
```

Just be sure when you are collecting the token you need have the offline_access token bcoz without that the token will expire soon and if you have that offline access too then your token will not expire , not even in 60 days .

Good Luck

Comment: Isn't offline_access deprecated? [source](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your album and the photos in it are public, you shouldn't have to get an OAuth token (for now at least).

If you get data when you browse to `https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos` where ALBUM_ID is your album's id, you'll be all right.

In your script you can do something like this:

```
$fb_data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos') );
foreach ($fb_data['images'] as $img) {
    sprintf('<img src="%s" height="%d" width="%d" />', $img['source'], $img['height'], $img['width'] );
}
```

If the item isn't public, create a connector app and you can use the APP_ID and APP_SECRET as an access token using the php SDK.

Comment: Hmm, the only response I get to an album I toggled as public is: `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } } ` Maybe I'm using the incorrect album id? What is the album for a URL of the form: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzz&type=3

Comment: The easiest way to find it is using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Type in the username or id for the owner of the album into the "GET" box and then add `/albums` to the end of it. That will give you a list of all the albums and their ids.

Comment: Looking at one of my albums from the front end, it looks like the id is `xxxxxxxxxxxxx` in your url scheme. However, this is less reliable. Not all objects return an id you can use in an API call from a front end url.

Comment: Digging through the Graph API Explorer, the only way I was able to get my photos in a public album was with an API Key with the user_photo permissions enabled. Removing the API causes the request to return empty data.